What is the completion with respect to a topology
I am reading the book "Vertex Algebras and Algebraic Curves: Second Edition" by Edward Frenkel and David Ben-Zvi.
In section 2.1.2 (page 26), two versions of Heisenberg Lie algebra are introduced. They are $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{H}'$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is defined from the central extension $0\to \mathbb{C}1\to \mathcal{H}\to \mathbb{C}((t))\to 0$, while $\mathcal{H}'$ is by $0\to \mathbb{C}1\to \mathcal{H}\to \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]\to 0$. Then, it says:

$H$ is the completion of $H′$ with respect to the topology in which the basis of open neighborhoods of $0$ is formed by the subspaces $t^N\mathbb{C}[t]$, $N\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I am confused with the connection between completeness and topology in this claim because I thought completeness is a property of metric spaces not for topological spaces. So, I tried to consider the mertic topolgy, in which $t^N\mathbb{C}[t]$ are considered as the $\epsilon$-balls to define the topology in this space under a metric $d$. However, I cannot find any metric to induce this topology.
So, how can I understand this claim?

Define a function
$$
|\ |_\infty:\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$
by
$$
|P(z)|_\infty=2^N\qquad\text{if $P(z)=az^{-N}+\sum_{k>-N}a_kz^k$ and $a\neq0$}
$$
and $|0|_\infty=0$.
Then $|\ |_\infty$ is an absolute value (i.e. satisfies all the usual properties) and so the function
$$
d_\infty(P(z),Q(z))=|P(z)-Q(z)|_\infty
$$
defines a metric on $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$.
